# Get value in URL PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

When I submit a form with wrong id's, the url is set like this :

```
url-test.com/connexion/?login-failed
```

I want to trigger login-failed to make conditions.

Here's my code, but it does not work

```
$login_failed = $_GET['login-failed'];

if($login_failed) {
    $error = 'Oups failed';
}

//My form
<?php wp_login_form(); ?>
<p><?php if(isset($error)) {echo $error;} ?></p>
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What does not work? Is the error not showing? Is the form not showing? Please explain / clarify the issue.

Comment: The error message is not showing

Answer (score 3):

```
if(isset($login_failed)) {
    $error = 'Oups failed';
}
```

You have to check that it's isset.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't working, because you're store the value of `$_GET['login-failed]`, but actually there's no value. If you change `?login-failed` to `?login-failed=1`, it should works.

Otherwise, you should check if variable [isset](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.isset.php), e.g:

```
$login_failed = isset( $_GET['login-failed'] ) ? true : false;
```